# Creating and running a .bat file

Tags: python

I am trying to make a Python program that creates and runs .bat files. I have figured out how to run .bat files but I am stuck on how to change the file type of created files in my program. Currently Python creates .txt files but I wish to create a .bat file.

Comment: Any code? What do You have so far? SO is not a place where You come and ask people to write code for You, but rather to help You when You hit a wall.

Comment: Batch files _are_ text. They just have a different extension. Are you choosing a `.txt` or `.bat` extension for those files?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As @Fejs mentioned above this site isn't a code writing service. Please take a moment to re-read the guidelines for asking questions here in the [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new text file and name it anything you like. In this example we'll name it "my-batch.bat".

```
file = open("my-batch.bat", "w")

file.write("hello world in the new file\n")
file.write("and another line")

file.close()
```